# Error with new file, 404 Not Found, App Engine for Python

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, http-status-code-404, wsgi

I have a website running on Google App Engine for Python. I've inherited the code-base and am trying to piece things together myself. I'm trying to accomplish the "simple" task of creating a new page on the website and linking to it from a toolbar. So, I created a new file, lets call it mypage.html, in the main directory.

Here's the code I use for linking, within the index.html file:

```
 <li {% if mypage_selected %}class='active'{% endif %}>
   <a href='/mypage'>My Page</a>
 </li>
```

And here's the code I use for handling the link, as declared in my main.py file:

```
class MyPagePage(BaseHandler):
  def get(self):
    template_values = {
      'mypage_selected': True,
      'session': self.session,
    }
    self.response.out.write(
      template.render(get_path("mypage.html"), template_values))
```

Finally, I added a reference to the page here (also in main.py):

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
  ('/', MainPage),
  ...
  ('/mypage/?', MyPagePage),
], debug=True, config=webapp2conf)
```

My new file is indeed at mypage.html. However, when I run this, the link shows up, but clicking it takes me to http://mydomain.net/mypage which gives a 404 Not Found error. Any ideas what could be happening?

EDIT: Here is the handler portion of my app.yaml:

```
handlers:
- url: /
  script: main.app
- url: /index\.html
  script: main.app
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
- url: /api.*
  script: api.app
- url: /blog/.*/edit/?
  script: dj.app
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

On an additional note: I tried navigating to mypage.html, and that gives me a 404 also. Very stumped here. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Note the `/mypage/?` in your handler.  That at least has to match, but your link is to `'/mypage'` so you get a 404.

Comment: Other links were formatted in the same way, so I just did the same. I made the change you suggested (linked to '/mypage/'), but still getting the same 404 Not Found.

Comment: You haven't included your mapping in app.yaml.  The problem will be url to handler mapping.  What did you change it too ?  Chances are what you changed it too is wrong too.  Do you understand the regex you have defined for your handler mapping?

Comment: To clarify, I tried changing my link to '/mypage' to '/mypage/' to match the handler, but that didn't work. Later, I tried changing the handler and the link both to '/mypage?' and '/mypage' respectively, but that didn't work either.

Comment: As I said earlier we can't see you app.yaml, you could also have a problem there.

Answer (score 0):

a few things.
I would highly recommend using a boilerplate application like [gae-boilerplate](https://github.com/coto/gae-boilerplate).  This will help with a lot of these first time problems with google appengine.  It's lightweight and will get you started on making your own projects quickly.  The reason I recommend it is because by default it resolves strict slash problems (the difference between /mypage and /mypage/) by using

```
from webapp2_extras.routes import RedirectRoute
from web.handlers import handlers
secure_scheme = 'https'

_routes = [
    RedirectRoute('/', handlers.MainPage, name='main', strict_slash=True),
    RedirectRoute('/mypage/', handlers.mypagepage, name='mypage', strict_slash=True),
    ...
```

and in your handlers you could have:

```
class mypagepage(BaseHandler):
    @user_required
    def get(self):
        params = {}
        return self.render_template('mypage.html', **params)
```